# a text in a text

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

> Organizations, ranging from multi-national for proft corporations to
>   nonprofit charities, keep secrets for competitive advantage, tomeet
>   legal requirements, or, in some ases, to conceal nefrious behavior.
>   ew products under development, uniquemanufacturing techniques, or
>   simply lists of customers are types of information protected by trade
>   secret laws. The patent system encourages inventors to publish
>   information in exchange for a limited time monopoly on its use, though
>   patent applications are initially secret. Secret societies use secrecy
>   as a way to attract members by creating a sense of importance.
>
> Shell companies may be used to launder money from criminal activity,
>   to finance terrorism, or to evade taxes. Registers of beneficial
>   ownership aim at fighting corporate secrecy in that sense.
>
> Other laws require organizations to keep certain information secret,
>   such as medical records (HIPAA in the U.S.), or financial reports that
>   are under preparation (to limit insider trading). Europe has
>   particularly strict laws about database rivacy.
>
> In many countries, neoiberal reforms of government have included
>   expanding the outsourcing of government tasks and functions to private
>   businesses with the aim of improving efficiency and effectiveness in
>   government administration. However, among the criticisms of these
>   reforms is the claim that the pervsive use of
>   "Commercial-in-confidence" (or secrecy) clauses in contracts between
>   government and private providers further limits public accountability
>   of governments and prevents proper public scrutiny of the performance
>   and probity of the private companies. Concerns have been raised that
>   'commercial-in-confidence' is open to abuse because it can be
>   deliberatel used to hide corporate or government maladministration
>   and even corruption.

*from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secrecy*

**Can you find the hidden message?**

Comment: More like a text "out of" a text!

Comment: As @Silenus said, it's rather a text _not_ in the text.

Comment: ㅤ***must... ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤㅤ  resist...  ㅤㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤurge... ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤto... ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤ ㅤedit....***

Comment: StringForever:  If you’re going to post puzzles like this, you might want to consider [this technique](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4627/19765#4689).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The deleted letters spell

> I can play